# JQuery getJSON doesn't work in IE

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql

I created a simple html in which I download data from MYSQL using php and jQuery. It works fine in Chrome(data refresh every 5 sec) but in IE even if the `window.setInterval` works fine the data downloads only once when the document is loaded for first time and after that the data is not refreshing.

```
function myFunc(){
    console.log("it works");
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $.getJSON("http://taxipolis.gr/phpfiles/drivers/get_alldrivers_coordinate_html.php",
            function (data) {
        });
    });
} 
window.setInterval(myFunc,5000);
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: is that a cross domain request?

Comment: Which version of IE and which version of jQuery? Anything in the console?

Comment: Why are you using `$(document).ready(function(){` inside a function? Also use `console.log` when you are only debugging it.

Comment: Because I am noob in html code.I think that yes is a cross domain request.And the Version of IE is 11 and Jquery i think that is 1.8.2

Comment: Also it gives me nothing in the console except one message that i created to see if setInterval works

Comment: i removed $(document).ready() and it still the same @Satpal

Comment: what is the network tab showing?

Comment: I checked my console in chrome and Also in IE and the difference is that in chrome every 5 sec says that XHR finished loading but in IE console keep being empty

Comment: In Chrome show me my php file with status code 200 and in IE is empty @Anoop

Comment: Sorry my mistake in IE show status code 304 in my request

Comment: @Psiroulis did you check that solution?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to use `XDomainRequest` for ie. Try with this code

```
var xdr = new XDomainRequest();
xdr.onload = function() { alert("READY"); };
 xdr.open("GET", "http://taxipolis.gr/phpfiles/drivers/get_alldrivers_coordinate_html.php");
xdr.send();
```

Checkout this  [**link**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd573303%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)  for more info

Comment: I tried but it says that XDomainRequest is not define

Comment: It may show that error on other browsers. But it will work on ie. You need to write code for finding the browser first and make the call accordingly

Comment: It gives me the same error on all browsers.(Chrome safari Ie).

Comment: I cahnge the:$.getJSON with $.ajax and i put cache: false and the network tag shows me status code 200 at my request.So maybe it was cache problem?

Comment: I fixed it my friend.It was a problem with the cache.Thank you very much for your time.@Anoop